# Woocommerce Products Per Page plugin issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I activated the Product Per Page plugin for Woocommerce and i have this message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: 
behaviour in /var/www/shop/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-products-per-page/objects/wppp-dropdown.php on line 30
Notice: Undefined index: 
behaviour in /var/www/shop/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-products-per-page/objects/wppp-dropdown.php on line 32
```

Wordpress version: 3.9

Woocommerce version: 2.1.7

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try disabling and reenabling the plugin? What are on lines 30 and 32 of the `wppp-dropdown.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

What theme do you use? I've had an another report on the Wordpress forums with the same notice. This was on the Genesis framework.

I will put out an release (probably) this weekend which will fix this.

Other than that I believe it is unusual to get an notice error on a live website, do you have WP_DEBUG on in your wp-config.php?

Anyhow stay up to date in [this topic](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/github-repo-4).

PS. I recommend to open an support topic in the Wordpress forums next time if you need support, I found this by coincidence :).

Comment: update (1.0.10) just released with the fix you need!